# Is makeStyles still able to be used in MUI v5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently migrating an MUI app to v5 and keep getting errors when rendering. The docs say "The `makeStyles` JSS utility is no longer exported from `@mui/material/styles`. You can use `@mui/styles/makeStyles` instead." I believe I have followed everything on the migration guide but I'm currently getting the below error. [image: error I am getting when rendering]

Any help greatly appreciated!